# Interval dates from two rows MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sample data of date in the following table on MySQL:

```
Start       End         Source
=====       ===         ====
2017-01-01  2017-02-14  T
2017-02-17  2017-02-28  T
2017-03-10  2017-03-15  T
```

And I want the interval date from End date to Start date. For ex:

```
 (2017-02-17) - 2017-02-14) = 3 days or (2017-03-10)-(2017-02-28) = 10 days
```

Any ideas on where to start? A lot of the reading I've done just to get interval between two dates in one row. Thank you.

Comment: Please consider to choose the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use DATEDIFF() function in mysql

your answer should be

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Start,End) AS DiffDate from table
```

you can refer to this

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to get the difference between enddate from row 1 and startdate from row 2, and so on. 
You have another identifier ? So i think you maybe need a "LEFT JOIN" or a subquery to handle this.

```
SELECT a.id, a.start, a.end, b.start, b.end, b.start - a.end AS `DIFF`
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON b.id = a.id -1
```

So you have two results in one row and you can use diff and intervall as you do for one line .

I hope this idea helps you in the right direction

Comment: Hey, better you use a "LEFT JOIN". Because otherwise you dont have a result for your first row, because when your first id is 1 " ON b.id = a.id -1 "  .

Comment: This only works if the id of the previous period is exactly one less than the id of the one you compare with.

Comment: This is trtue, but when it is not this, he can show us the structure and we can optimize the query. Was just a first Idea. Let us brainstorm ^^

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is finding the time difference between two consecutive rows in the same table.

You can do it that way:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Start, t1.End, 
       datediff(max(t2.End ), t1.Start) as minutes
FROM t as t1 LETF JOIN t as t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID 
       and t2.End < t1.Start
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Start, t1.End
```

Comment: datediff expects only 2 parameters. You have 3 parameters in your usage?

Comment: @Krishnakumar `datediff` expects 3 parameters. [You can see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: Hi, In MySQL only 2 > [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Answer (score 0):

you should simply use `join` to calculate those date

```
select concat(datediff(n1.start,n2.end),' ',repeat('days',1)) as days 
from table_name n1 
join table_name n2 
on n2.end < n1.start;
```

see here [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3daf4f/2)

if you don't need repeat "days" than simple use this query

```
select datediff(n1.start,n2.end) 
from your_table n1 
join your_table n2 
on n2.end < n1.start;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the query, and let me know if it worked or not?

```
SET @dateDiff=NULL;SET @dateDiff2='';
SELECT diff.dateDiffR AS dateDifference FROM (
SELECT aa.`end`,aa.`start`,IF(@dateDiff IS NULL,@dateDiff:=aa.end,0) AS try,
DATEDIFF(aa.`start`,@dateDiff) AS dateDiffR,
IF(@dateDiff!=@dateDiff2,@dateDiff2:=@dateDiff,0) AS try1,
IF(DATE(@dateDiff)!=DATE(aa.end),@dateDiff:=aa.end,NULL) AS assign 
FROM test.`dateCheck` aa ) diff WHERE diff.dateDiffR>0
```